# Can we give a custom voice to AVSpeechSynthesizer

Tags: ios, avspeechsynthesizer

Hi I am developing an IOS application and I want to convert text to speech. For this I am using IOS `AVSpeechSynthesizer` SDK.

My question is that can we give it our custom voice other than the defaults voices of IOS. **For example can I give the voice of a child speaking a string?**

Or there is another SDK for that?
And `AVSpeechSynthesizer` is only for IOS7 or can it work on IOS 6 as well?

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: There is nothing built in IOS only two default voices one male and one female voice. You have to use some third party library.

Comment: which library did you use? What was your use case? Asking because we are looking at providing similar functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to license a third-party speech synthesizer for that - it's not possible with anything Apple has built into iOS.

Off the top of my head, the only one I can think of that includes children's voices is [Acapela](http://www.acapela-group.com/acapela-for-ios/) though I'm not 100% sure if they support them in their iOS library.