# How do we add text-to-speech functionality in iOS 12?

Tags: ios, frameworks, text-to-speech, ios12

I'm trying to build an app for iOS 12 which would have the basic functionality of converting text-to-speech. I am aware of the stock AVSpeechSynthesizer framework Apple provides, but I also want to explore other options. How do I change the voice and add a custom voice to the framework? Can I do that? If not, can I explore other third-party APIs? It would be great if you could provide some examples of other frameworks.  Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we give a custom voice to AVSpeechSynthesizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189778/can-we-give-a-custom-voice-to-avspeechsynthesizer)

Comment: TRy this -> https://www.ikiapps.com/tips/2015/12/30/setting-voice-for-tts-in-ios

Comment: here is a great tutorial on google speech to text ios integration. [google STT integration](https://medium.com/@ambrose12silveira/google-speech-to-text-stt-api-integration-and-training-model-with-ios-swift-part-i-46519bd41c75)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should try google Cloud speech Api :

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Objective-C

tutorial : https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-integrate-google-cloud-text-to-speech-api-into-your-ios-app-140ab7be42ae

Comment: Hi. Thanks fo sharing these links. I tried to inegrate Google Cloud TTS API but it doesn't work well. It keeps giving me an error and the code is awfully long and complex. Do you know any other easy to use TTS APIs? Your help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi can you tell me error that you are facing while integration

Comment: Invalid response: ["error": {
    code = 403;
    details =     (
                {
            "@type" = "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help";
            links =             (
                                {
                    description = "Google developer console API key";
                    url = "https://console.developers.google.com/project/775082957374/apiui/credential";
                }
            );
        }
    );
    message = "Requests from this ios client application <empty> are blocked.";
    status = "PERMISSION_DENIED";
}]

Comment: I don't know what permission is getting denied

Answer (score 1):

to solve your error please go to APIkey and delete your bundle id from it and save and run your app again